# Return same view does not seem to refresh page

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have controller methods that do stuff with WMI classes (waking selected machine, opening or closing processes, initiating an RDP session) and then reload the current view. To reload I've tried the following:

```
    return View();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "RenderNodesController");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

The methods all execute successfully with regards to performing the WMI calls, but the return statement doesn't reload the page. If I refresh the page manually it reloads and displays changed information as expected. Also rather weirdly if I step through the return statements in the debugger I see that the view's Index method executes so debugging seems not to help in this instance.
I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just to update, I was wrong about return statement calling the view's index method to execute, as it doesn't - apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why
    return View();
and similar doesn't execute but in the end I got it working using Javascript's window.location.reload(), full script below for completeness:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.checkbox').click(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("CallProcess", "RenderNodes")';
            var networkname = $(this).data("networkname");
            var processname = $(this).data("processname");
            var filename = $(this).data("filename");
            var start = $(this).is(':checked');
            $.post(url, { NetworkName: networkname, ProcessName: processname, FileName: filename, Start: start },
                function (data) {
                    $("#CallProcess").html(data);
                });
            window.location.reload(true);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why you have to do that either but it also worked for me. This saved me some time for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add some explanation to this answer:

Because you're performing an AJAX request, it won't reload the user's browser page on success, all it will do is return the results of the action method called within the result parameter. $.post is a shorthand version of $.ajax so the behaviour will be the same.

Solution:
Use for example `location.reload(true)` (as you  did).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution is a little tricky, but it works. Instead of using a

```
return View("/MyRedirectView.cshtml");
```

in the controller, I used a

```
return RedirectToAction("MyRedicrectAction");
```

and the action is this:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult MyRedicrectAction()
    {
        return View("/MyRedirectView.cshtml");
    }
```